# passing std::list from one function to another by value

Tags: c++, list, std

I have a C++ program as given below. I am trying to pass a std::list from one function to another by value. I expect the list to be accessible in the caller function by means of an iterator? I expect that the return will call the copy constructor of `std::list` and it will be accessible in the caller. Is my assumption wrong ? If not why am I getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

const char *sy_path = "/var/log";
struct Setting
{
    typedef std::list<const Setting*> List;

    const char*     path;
    const char*     filename;
    const char*     name;

    int def;
    int min;
    int max;

    struct Original
    {
        const char*     filename;
        const char*     name;

        Original(const char* filename_, const char* name_) 
                    :filename(filename_), name(name_)
        {

        }
    }original;
    static const List settings();
}; 

const Setting::List Setting::settings()
{
    const Setting c_settings[] =
    {                                                       //default min  max      
         {  sy_path, "cs.cfg",      "num_a",                 1,    1,    29,            Original("sys.cfg", "num_a") }
        ,{  sy_path, "cs.cfg",      "num_b",                 1,    1,    6,             Original("sys.cfg", "num_b") }
        ,{  sy_path, "cs.cfg",      "num_c",                 1,    1,    29,            Original("sys.cfg", "num_c") }
    };

    Setting::List lst;

    int numelem = sizeof(c_settings) / sizeof(Setting); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numelem; i++)
    {
        const Setting & tmpSetting = c_settings[i]; 
        lst.push_back(&tmpSetting);
    }

    return lst;
}

static int get_settings(void)
{
    Setting::List lst;
    lst = Setting::settings();

    for (Setting::List::const_iterator it = lst.begin() ; it != lst.end(); ++it)
    {
        const Setting *cs = *it;
        std::cout << "path: " <<cs->path << "filename: " <<cs->filename << "name: " << cs->name << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    get_settings();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're returning a list of pointers to data that has long since been destructed before you iterate it in `get_settings`. Try changing the list to `std::list<Settings>` instead.

Comment: Why, why, why? Not the problem, but why do so many people write assignments instead of initializations? `Setting::List lst; lst = Setting::settings();` should be `Setting::List lst = Setting::settings();`. There's no reason to create a List object and immediately throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `return lst;` will return a copy of `lst`. The problem is that you put in `lst` pointers to data located on the stack (`const Setting c_settings[]` variable). These pointers become invalid once you return from function, hence the segmentation fault. The solution is to either allocate memory for your settings on heap, or use a `std::list<Setting>`.

```
typedef std::list<Setting> List;

lst.push_back(c_settings[i]); // make sure you have the right copy constructor
```

or

```
lst.push_back(new Setting(c_settings[i])); // make sure you have the right copy constructor
```

Also, I would avoid usage of `const char *` and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: are you refereeing to `path`,`filename`, `name` etc which is `const char *` ? And how do you mean std::list<Setting> ?

Comment: I believe you are safe with path, filename, name, in this case, since you initialized them with string literals (don't know about sy_path). However, ```c_settings``` creates 3 Setting elements locally to this function (and on the stack), so they go away when returning from function. By ```std::list<Setting>``` I mean make a list not of pointers, but Setting elements.